Error in Back Substitution Function For Gaussian Elimination of a matrix
I'm trying to build a program to perform Gaussian Elimination on an matrix, I was able to create a function to convert the matrix into row echelon form. But my Back Substitution program has an error which I tried to solve in many ways but couldn't.
Here's my code:
def back_substitution(M):
    """
    Perform back substitution on an augmented matrix (with unique solution) in reduced row echelon form to find the solution to the linear system.

    Parameters:
    - M (numpy.array): The augmented matrix in row echelon form with unitary pivots (n x n+1).

    Returns:
    numpy.array: The solution vector of the linear system.
    """
    
    # Make a copy of the input matrix to avoid modifying the original
    M = M.copy()

    # Get the number of rows (and columns) in the matrix of coefficients
    num_rows = M.shape[0]

    if num_rows == 0:
        return np.array([])
    
    # Iterate from bottom to top
    for row in reversed(range(num_rows)): 
        
        substitution_row = M[row, :-1]  # Extract the row without the last element

        # Get the index of the first non-zero element in the substitution row
        index = np.argmax(substitution_row)

        # Iterate over the rows above the substitution_row
        for j in range(row): 

            row_to_reduce = M[j, :-1]

            # Get the value of the element at the found index in the row to reduce
            value = row_to_reduce[index]
            
            # Perform the back substitution step using the formula row_to_reduce -> row_to_reduce - value * substitution_row
            row_to_reduce -= value * substitution_row

            # Replace the updated row in the matrix
            M[j, :-1] = row_to_reduce
            
    # Extract the solution from the last column
    solution = M[:, -1]
    
    return solution

The Error:
Wrong output for test case check_matrix_1. 
    Expected:
     [-0.33333333 -1.33333333  2.33333333].
    Got:
 [4.         1.7        2.33333333].
Wrong output for test case check_matrix_2. 
    Expected:
     [0.7857143  1.64285714 0.        ].
    Got:
 [9.         1.64285714 0.        ].
Wrong output for test case check_matrix_3. 
    Expected:
     [19. -2.  1.].
    Got:
 [9. 6. 1.].
 1  Tests passed
 3  Tests failed


Thanks in advance!
I tried modifying the row_to_reduce variable in everyway I could think of but couldn't find a soltuion.

Please provide example inputs alone with the desired outputs.

Why have you set index to that of the MAXIMUM value in the row and not simply that of the pivot? Why don’t you include the last element (I.e. the RHS) in your row operations?

Assuming matrix M is full rank and in a row echelon form. Then you can use the following:
import numpy as np

def back_solve(M):
  n = M.shape[0]
  solution = np.zeros(n)
  for i in reversed(range(n)):
    solution[i] =  (M[i,-1] - solution @ M[i, :-1]) / M[i,i]
  return solution


EXAMPLE:
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,4,5],[0,0,6]])

np.linalg.solve(a, [1,2,3])
array([-0.25 , -0.125,  0.5  ])

back_solve(np.c_[a, [1,2,3]])
array([-0.25 , -0.125,  0.5  ])


Error:
matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5 is different from 4)

@ShamalLakshan you never gave an example. Also the code works in the example i gave. If you have a rectangular array, then you cannot do back substitution. Try using np.linalg.solve and see whether there is an error. If there is, then back substitution wont work. That is maybe because of rank deficiency
